# Different application signatures

Tags: android, android-emulator, reinstall

I made a few updates to the code for my android app and tried to test it in my phone but Eclipse gives me an error saying `Re-installation failed due to different application signatures`. Now I understand by googling that I have to uninstall the package using adb but I don't know how to do it? I mean it asks me to use adb uninstall in a shell but I have no experience in developing android apps using command line.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could also just delete the application from your phone going to "Settings" -> "Applications" -> "Manage applications". Find your app and delete it.

Comment: Great it worked thank you! Sometimes simple and obvious solutions are hard to see :)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the device and run

```
adb uninstall com.mypackagename.myappname
```